# why this useEffect (first one) doesn't run on dependency change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

```js
export default function App() {

  // as the useState runs before useEffect, 
  // it means count is avaliable to use in the useEffect 
  // but why it is not running?
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("I only run on first render.", count);
  },[count]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("I runs on every render/re-render", count);
  });

  // if i use const in place of var, it throws error of lexical scope
  // but as useState run before the effect the count is already in scope, right?
  var [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("run on first render and whenever the count changes", count);
  }, [count]);


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>Count: {count}</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount((prev) => prev + 1)}>count +</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I think this is the order of execution for first render:

run lazy intializers (or we can say run useState) -> redner -> dom update -> broser paint -> run effect

And for re-render: all the things except lazy intializers and effect cleanup before running new effects.

Answer (score 2):

`Eslint` warns like this

> var count: number 'count' was used before it was defined.
> (no-use-before-define)eslint

You need to move `useState` for `count` declaration before the `useEffect` which uses it as a dependency.

```
  var [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("I only run on first render.", count);
  }, [count]);
```

Comment: yes in your case it would work fine.  If useState runs before useEffect i think it means that the count is registerd in lexical scope right? Just to get this thing  I have put the useState after useEffect intentionally.

Comment: `Just to get this thing I have put the useState after useEffect intentionally` intentionally for what purpose? You need to rethink something @AmitDhaterwal

Comment: I was wondering how the useEffect compare the dependency, you told me when it processes the code (i.e line no 7), in that case, it makes sense for the count to be undefined. And I think after dom update and browser pain the useEffect fires its callback and at that time the count is defined and holds new value. Am I right @TKoL? ```You need to rethink something``` can you give me heads up here, i'm little confuse. Thanks though for helping.

Comment: ever time line 7 runs, `count` will ALWAYS be undefined. `count` doesn't get defined until this line: `var [count, setCount] = useState(0);` And that's true EVERY time this function runs, not just the first time.

Comment: ```JavaScript only hoists declarations, not initializations```. Got it, boss.  I used ```var ``` so that the count is HOISTED  but my bad I took initialization for granted Looks like i need to rethink javascript after all. You are awesome.

Answer (score 1):

You're first effect is using `count` before it has been defined, so it is always `undefined`.

Comment: if it is undefined then the why 2nd effect (which is without dependency) is able to log count

Comment: As you already noted effects run after rendering. So when the 2nd effect runs, `count` is defined. But your first effect won't run because at the time when the dependency array is checked, `count` is not yet defined.